# The definite article in a story heading

Tags: grammar, articles

> The Luckiest Man

is the title of a story.
What is the definite article in the above title or heading referring to?

Comment: Presumably something happens in the story to cause the protagonist to be described as "The luckiest man alive" or similar. The title must be a reference to this.

Comment: People may say 'I saw the loveliest cat today!' without feeling the need to specify out of which collection or group the cat was the loveliest.

Comment: Per @MichaelHarvey, “I had the **best** time at her party” can mean simply that I had a very good time. It need not have its literal superlative sense, which would be either that nobody else had a better time at the party than I did, or that on no other occasion have I had a better time than I did at the party.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article is used for someone or something *specific*, so it is evidently a story about a *specific* man who is lucky for reasons I would expect to be revealed in the story.

This is quite common - most stories focus on a central, often titular, character. "*The very hungry Caterpillar*" is a story about a specific caterpillar who is very hungry. It just wouldn't sound as noteworthy if it was "*a very hungry caterpillar*". It makes them sound commonplace. If every caterpillar is very hungry, why does one deserve a book of his own?

Answer (score 0):

In general, "the" indicates a specific or unique noun. The indefinite article "a/an" roughly means "one of many". Any noun that is modified with a *superlative adjective* is by definition unique, so we use "the" before these nouns.

In your example, "luckiest" is a superlative adjective, so "man" is unique, and can only take "the". It's incorrect to use "a/an" because the man is not one of many luckiest men, but the only one.

If a noun is modified with a *comparative adjective*, a simple adjective, or no adjective at all, then "a/an" or "the" are possible.